# Codeigniter : 404 Page Not Found The page you requested was not found

Tags: php, html, codeigniter

Here i am trying to load abous us page. But the requested page is not found.Please provide solution for this issue.

View:

```
 <ul class="nav nav-pills">
                    <li><a href="<?php echo $site ?>">HOME</a></li>
              <li><a href="<?php echo $site ?>/CI_timeline/loadaboutus">ABOUT US</a></li></ul>
```

Controller:

```
public function loadaboutus()
    {
        $data=$this->data;
        $this->load->view('aboutus',$data);
    }
```

Comment: have you removed index.php from url?? try changing the url.
`<?php echo $site ?>/index.php/CI_timeline/loadaboutus`

Answer (score 2):

Mybe you did not add index.php

```
<li><a href="<?php echo $site ?>/index.php/CI_timeline/loadaboutus">ABOUT US</a></li>
```

or

```
<li><a href="<?php echo site_url() ?>/CI_timeline/loadaboutus">ABOUT US</a></li>
```

make sure your controller name start with capital letter.

Comment: @NiranjanNRaju Comment is not an answer

Comment: i do not have permission to comment because my point are less to i answer it.

Answer (score 2):

Make sure you have written the proper controller name both in "li" and also at the top of your controller page.

Answer (score 1):

```
public function loadaboutus()
{
    $data=$this->data;
    $this->load->view('aboutus',$data);
}

Try this:

public function loadaboutus()
{
    $this->load->view('aboutus');
}
```

Comment: Your data is empty variable  $data=$this->data;  and then not open the choosen page that solve...

Answer (score 0):

Make sure your base folder name and the name you write in $config['base_url'] is the same.

Answer (score 0):

Use

```
<?php echo base_url('/ContollerName/function Name') ;?>
```

and in your controller , add

```
public function loadaboutus()
    {
       $this->load->helper('url');
        $data=$this->data;
        $this->load->view('aboutus',$data);
    }
```